# Multi site licences

Tags: multi-domain

If you are running multiple domains on one craft install as suggested here https://craftcms.com/support/sharing-craft-files
What are the pro licence implications?

Answer (score 3):

If the multiple sites are based on sub-domains (i.e. site1.site.com, site2.site.com), then a single `craft/config/license.key` file will cover all of the sites with no issues.

Comment: thx Brad
and if its different domains......add a licence for each?